# CSS Transparent Long Shadows

Tags: jquery, html, css, dropshadow

So I was tasked with creating long shadows but on a textured background.  The other tutorials online are all how to do it with a solid background which looks pretty terrible on textures or images for backgrounds.

I got pretty close with it, trying a few different techniques but I came down to two possibilities, each with problems, so if anyone can help me debug either it would be greatly appreciated. These are not cross browser, I am just trying to figure out bare minimum if it is doable so please ignore lack of prefixes etc.

Type 1: Pure CSS
Using the Skew option in CSS I was able to add two blocks on the left and bottom with a gradient. Then skewing each 45 degrees I get close to the desired effect but there is a line in between where the shadows don't perfectly meet that i can't get to go away without overlap:
http://jsfiddle.net/mfeola/4bfrkagu/

```
.block:before, .block:after{
    content:"";position:absolute; display:block;
}

.block:before{top:0; left:100%; height:100%; width:0; padding-right:100%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: skew(0deg, 45deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
.block:after{top:100%; left:0; width:100%; height:0; padding-top:100%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

Type 2: Javascript
With rotational math figured out, I was able to rotate a gradient box to make a perfect shadow. The problem is if the size of the box changes, the angle of the shadow changes and that doesn't work for what I am trying to do. I would like it to work universally.  I included a textarea on this one when I was figuring out the math:
http://jsfiddle.net/mfeola/tpdhLqs1/

Comment: If you change the width of the right shadow to 200x, the height of the container, the linear gradients would match up better on a diagonal http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4bfrkagu/6/

Comment: I will do that, thank you :) The shadows really line up much better this way

Comment: What i wound up doing, was making the bottom shadow a square (responsive with height 0 padding top 100%) comes up with the same outcome. In fact now it works with any height automatically now! thank you so much for leading me in the right direction! I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a border gradient to fill the gap.

Was trying it out from this link: https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Couldn't get the exact colors right, but I think you should be able to do this using some border gradient formatting as follows:

```
.top-to-bottom {
    border-right: 0 !important;
    border-left: 0 !important;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    border: 1px solid;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1))) 1 100%;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)) 1 100%;
    -moz-border-image:
      -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)) 1 100%;    
    -o-border-image:
      -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)) 1 100%;
    border-image:
      linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)) 1 100%;
}
```

Was messing around with it a bit here: http://jsfiddle.net/4bfrkagu/13/ but couldn't get the coloring right - figured I could leave that to you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, now i have a dark line all the time instead of an empty line

Comment: Oh, I think I see what's going on... it's almost like the border, when on top of the background the two transparent backgrounds overlap, so what you see is what it would look like if you added both opacities. - Take a look at this fiddle, I got rid of all that border garbage and just moved the pseudo element down 1px. It's the same effect. So what I would suggest is instead of using `rgba` and picking an opacity, just pick the definitive color transitions with `rgb`. Then you should be able to use the border gradient trick

Comment: using anything but transparency won't look right on a textured background.  I updated the fiddle to look more like what I will need to do.  I think if I lower the transparency from a dark starting opacity to a lighter one the line will be barely noticeable so that should be fine for now.  If i didn't use alpha in the color then I would wind up with a weird color there anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that was going to be my next question - whether or not you needed it to be transparent. But yeah, yours looks good now - don't really notice any line if there is one.